# Trace options when logging to azure table storage

Tags: c#, azure, azure-table-storage

I have a web app that I have been working on and would like to have some logging added to it and so far it is working with the simple System.Diagnostics tracing mechanism. I configured the output table in the manage.windowsazure portal under  > configure > application diagnostics and turned on the switch for table storage logging. Now that it is outputting to the storage table I would like to add a dateTime column so I can query on it later.

I've seen that you can set the trace options for that to happen here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/a10k7w6c%28v=vs.110%29.aspx. I just don't know how to get access to the listener. I would think that the listener is managed by azure but is there a way to set the traceoptions via a config file or otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

Azure Table storage has a Timestamp column that will always be there(Along with PartitionKey and RowKey columns) and is controlled by the storage engine. so I assume if you are only looking for the datetime then you should be good.

Here is more info about these 3 columns in table storage:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/storage-table-design-guide/